# Append some HTML into the HEAD tag?

Tags: javascript, html, header

I want to add some style to head tag in html page using javascript.

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
h.innerHTML += '<style>a{font-size:100px;}</style>';
```

But when I run this code in IE8 I see this error message:
*Could not set the innerHTML property. Invalid target element for this operation.*

Any ideas?

Comment: Apart from the issue with IE not liking to set `innerHTML` on various elements like `<head>`: don't ever use `innerHTML+=`. You'd be serialising all the nodes inside the head element to HTML, adding a string and then parsing them back, losing all non-serialisable content in the process. This is always to be avoided.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create the `style` element with createElement:

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
var s = document.createElement("style");
s.type = "text/css"; 
s.appendChild(document.createTextNode("a{font-size:100px;}"));
h.appendChild(s);
```

Comment: Hi!

This code works in Chrome. But in IE I got this error: Unexpected call to method or property access.

Comment: I found the solution. Problem was in this line: s.appendChild(document.createTextNode("a{font-size:100px;}");

See how to fix it here: http://www.phpied.com/dynamic-script-and-style-elements-in-ie/

Answer (score 1):

you can try:

```js
let header = document.querySelector('head')
let newElement = document.createElement('p')
newElement.style.color = "lime"
newElement.style.fontSize = ".5rem"
header.append(newElement)
```

Comment: Please add more detail