# How add html elements to head element of page using javascript? (Cross Browser -> such as IE)

Tags: javascript, html, addition, head

How add html elements to head element of page using javascript? (show us both jQuery and javascrip, but js is so important)

There are some threads in stack about this, but none of show a way for html elements.

```
"<b>Test</b>"
```

For example one of them is :

[Append some HTML into the HEAD tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676336/append-some-html-into-the-head-tag)

As you see it's about adding css to head not html codes.

How can I do that?

Comment: what "html elements" are you talking about? An element like `<b>Test</b>` has nothing to do in the `head` section...

Comment: that b element is just for example...i am talking about other elements.

Comment: @MoonLight - Try giving real examples that show your actual problem instead of hypothetical examples that make no sense.

Comment: @MoonLight - What makes you think that the method will be different for an element that isn't a style element? The [style element **is** an HTML element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#h-14.2.3).

Comment: i am talking about frameset element -> we can add it to head.am i right?

Comment: <html>
<head>
<frameset cols="100%" rows="100%">
  <frame src="http://www.blabla.com/" />
</frameset>
<title>
</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>

Comment: i can not edit my Q anymore -> because of some edit

Comment: looking for something looklike innerHTML -> but does not work in IE

Comment: `frameset` should go into the `body` section, not the `head` section...

Comment: `frameset` should appear *instead* of body -> http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is invalid to put `<b>` elements inside the head element..

Allowed elements are found at http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/head.html (*read the **Permitted contents** section and links*)

Comment: i know -> that was just for example.

Comment: @Moonlight, the majority of html elements cannot go inside the `head` tag. Only a handful of elements is allowed (*added link in answer*). Perhaps you could elaborate a bit on what you want to achieve, so we can provide more detailed answers..

Answer (score 0):

Using this code you can append multiple script with rendomnumber in head section

```
 var MultiJsLink = ['js/enjoyhint.min.js', 'js/tab-help-common-on-off.js'];
    var jshtml ='';
    $(MultiJsLink).each(function(i){
    jshtml += '<script src='+MultiJsLink[i]+'?vrsn='+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)+'><\/script>';
});

$('head').append(jshtml);
```

Your script append like this:

```
<script src=js/enjoyhint.min.js?vrsn=332></script><script src=js/tab-help-common-on-off.js?vrsn=57></script>
```