# document.write() for adding a stylesheet causes document to be blank

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a stylesheet only on the condition that the browser is either Chrome or Opera. I have the following control flow using the YUI library:

```
  if ((Y.UA.chrome > 0) || (Y.UA.opera > 0)){
    document.write("<link rel='stylesheet' media='print' type='text/css' href='../../../css/style_ticket_printing_header.css'/>");
  }
```

Here is the conditionally attached css file, `style_ticket_printing_header.css`

```
@page 
{
  size: auto;  
  margin: 0mm;   
 }
```

Here is the full HTML:

https://gist.github.com/ebbnormal/b1cff9d45914bc2f63a4

When I run the page in Chrome, none of the `<div>`s that are defined within the `<body>` tag are rendered or are displayed within the DOM.

What is particularly confusing is that, when this CSS is loaded in the normal way (by simply referencing it via a `<link>` tag in the `<head>` of the page, all of the DOM are loaded perfectly.

And finally I know that it successfully renders the condition of seeing it is chrome as I formerly had an alert message in the body of the if block which successfully executed.

Comment: When you use `document.write()` after the document is finished, it implicitly wipes the whole document out and starts a fresh, empty one.

Comment: @Pointy Ah! So is there  a way to add the CSS, without using `document.write` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> document.write() for adding a stylesheet causes document to be blank

Right. When you use `document.write` after the main page parsing is complete, it implicitly does a `document.open`, which wipes out the page.

Instead, use `createElement` and `appendChild`:

```
if ((Y.UA.chrome > 0) || (Y.UA.opera > 0)){
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.rel = "stylesheet";
    link.media = "print";
    link.type = "text/css";
    link.href = "../../../css/style_ticket_printing_header.css";
    document.querySelector("head").appendChild(link);
}
```

Or if you really like to use HTML: :-)

```
if ((Y.UA.chrome > 0) || (Y.UA.opera > 0)){
    document.querySelector("head").insertAdjacentHTML(
        "beforeend",
        "<link rel='stylesheet' media='print' type='text/css' href='../../../css/style_ticket_printing_header.css'/>"
    );
}
```

*(Both of the above assume you have a `head` element, which you presumably do; it's required in a well-formed HTML document, either explicitly or because the browser adds it for you [but explicit is best].)*

---

About `querySelector`: It finds the first element that matches a CSS selector. It's supported by all modern browsers, and also IE8. (There's also `querySelectorAll`, which finds a *list* of matching elements.)

Comment: will it not work if I put the above script  in the `<head>` of the document?

Comment: @Thalatta: You mean the script in the answer? Yes, it will work. If you mean the script in the question, it would **if** it were evaluated **during** the main parsing of the page. Your description of the problem suggests that it's evaluated later, for instance in some kind of "the DOM / window is ready" callback.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your `<head>` tag in html file,

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    if ((Y.UA.chrome > 0) || (Y.UA.opera > 0)){
      document.write("<LI" + "NK rel='stylesheet' media='print' type='text/css' href='../../../css/style_ticket_printing_header.css'/>");
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

it may work.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to add the stylesheet into the head, take a look at this: [Append some HTML into the HEAD tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676336/append-some-html-into-the-head-tag)

The basic idea is to use

```
var newElement = document.createElement('element')
```

and

```
newElement.setAttribute('attr', 'val')
```